# Inserting data into LotusNotes Text List field with C#

Tags: .net, lotus-notes

I am porting some java code that writes to a Notes database into C#.  Generally, that is going well, however, I have come upon a hangup dealing with Text List fields in the Notes documents.  I am using the .Net Domino interop dlls.

in Java, I have this code:

```
doc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", recipients); // recipients is Vector<String>
```

I thought that something like this should work in C#

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", recipients); // recipients is List<string>
```

I have also tried:

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", recipients.ToArray());
```

However, both options throw a COMException: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector

What am I supposed to pass in there?  According to this (only Notes documentation I seem to find) http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/Main?OpenFrameSet, an array of strings looks like it should work.

**Edit:**

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", recipients.ToArray());
```

does work, I missed one line that wrote recipients above the one mentioned.  Makes you feel a little stupid, but I'll leave it up here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: Eric, I will suggest that you add your own answer as an answer and then mark the question as answered afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from the COM-documentation in Designer's Help, you should be able to use the AppendToTextList-method.

First get the item with NotesDocument's GetFirstItem. Then on the NotesItem object, use AppendToTextList.